# Create graphical element with selectable portions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm looking to create something like this using CSS:

[image: like this]

As I hover over each colored section, I want to be able to change the color of the section and have a popup appear.

I know that using a canvas with an image map & clickable area coords is one way to tackle this, but I'm wondering if there is perhaps an easier way that would allow me to create the graphic with CSS and set a class for each piece of it.

Comment: CSS isn't powerful enough to do this. Canvas would be the most appropriate if you want to draw this programmatically.

Comment: You *could* do this in just CSS of you were to split the image into three.  You could then use :hover and `background-image` to switch each arrow for a different coloured version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an SVG. The actual SVG markup can be embedded into your HTML as several grouped elements.

You can then wire up javascript events or target the elements with CSS `:hover`. Because the browser knows their exact shape, you can get pixel-accurate mouse overs.

```css
circle:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="red"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="150" cy="50" r="40" fill="green"/>
  <circle id="circle3" cx="200" cy="50" r="30" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Plenty of vector editing packages like Adobe Illustrator or Sketch can output SVG artwork. There are also [online SVG editors](https://www.catscarlet.com/site/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html).